# Hidden Iframes..? Seo tools detect iframes which I can not find in my html

Tags: html, iframe

I installed some browser SEO tools for Chrome, and they all detect some iframes which I can not find in my HTML.

Could I get some help in detecting them? As far as I know, I dont use any iframes.

The website is: [Firstidea.gr](http://www.firstidea.gr)

The home page shows 1 iframe, while for example the contact page shows 4 iframes!

Any help to understand the reason behind that, would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As i was searching on your website i saw you use jx_ui_Widget to make contact via chat widget. I know this widget as i used it myself. Well this widget is creating iframes for you.

On the contact page you have the widget and on your homepage you don't.
This widget also creates iframes on other pages to track visitors so you can talk to them live. 1 frame (like the one on your homepage) is for tracking the visitors. The other 3 (or more) is for creating the widget on your page

Comment: Thank you, you are right about zopim creating the 3 extra iframes. I completely unistalled this widget though, but I still get 1 iframe everywhere...

Comment: Can you tell me where the iframe is located. Its a little hard for me because the website uses a language i don't understand. Russian or something

Comment: This is my problem. That I can not locate it :-) I have no idea where it is, and what generates it. The language is Greek

Comment: I mean can you copy the data of the iframe from the chrome dev tool

Comment: The webtool just mentions that i have 1 iframe. It doest show its contents or its location...

Comment: You use a library in the root of your project. It's md5 protected. This might be the problem you're facing. I suggest you start using xdebugger. Install netbenas and use xdebugger

Comment: Thank you very much. I ll try that and see what happens :-)